# Importing JSON with dynamic fields with GraphQL and Gatsby

Tags: json, graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to import JSON files containing product categories with **gatsby-transformer-json** that contain multiple products with fields which have dynamic sub fields depending on the category they are in. There are hundreds of different categories so I would like to keep these subfields like "attributes" dynamic. They also might change over time. The client logic would handle this.

Unfortunately GraphQL only let's me query fields explicitly and the query needs to know all subfields.

This is the JSON:

```
{
    "name": "Car Hifi",
    "categorydesc": "This should be a very long text",
    "products": [{
            "name": "JVC KW-DB93BT",
            "attributes": {
                "Has USB": "JVC",
                "compatible formats": {},
                "Hands free": "true"
            },
            "advantages": {
                "0": "More bass",
                "1": "Less power consumption",
                "2": "Simple UI"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and this a query:

```
query MyQuery {
  dataJson {
    name
    categorydesc
    products {
      name
      attributes {
        // This should be dynamic
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can think of is to modify the `attributes` so that it becomes an array instead:

```
// from this
{
  "attributes": {
    "Has USB": "JVC",
    "compatible formats": {},
    "Hands free": "true"
  }
}

// to this
{
  "attributes": [
    {"label": "Has USB", "value": "JVC" },
    {"label": "compatible formats", "value": {} },
    {"label": "Hands free", "value": true },
  ]
}
```

Then you can query it:

```
query {
  dataJson {
    products {
      name
      attributes {
        label
        value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately `gatsby-transformer-json` is not that flexible, I think if you want to go down this route it's better to write your own source plugin (which isn't as difficult as it sounds) that transform the `attributes` field before feeding the data to Gatsby's `createNode`.

A few relevant links from the docs:

- https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-a-source-plugin/
- https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/

Comment: I tried with the array but somehow ended needing to query them explicitly still. The tip with the plugin seems to be the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: @Philipp note that if you're trying out by manipulating a single json file while all other json are untouched, it wouldn't work since gatsby determine the shape of data by the first json file it finds -- so you'd have to change them all, or at least remove all other json files temporary to see it working